# Mysql search for all string permutations

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to search a database column `varchar` for all permutations of a string delimited by spaces. For example:

```
search:  foo
matches: foo, foo bar, bar foo

search:  foo bar
matches: foo bar, bar foo, bar foo green, green foo bar
```

I am using PHP with PDO for generating the searches. I am having speed issues when creating and searching for strings with many words because there are so many possible permutations to create and include in the query. Below is the PHP code I am using to generate the permutations. Maybe there is a way to decrease the number of terms?

```php
function permutations($set) {
    $solutions = array($set);
    $n = count($set);
    $p = array_keys($set);
    $i = 1;
    while ($i < $n) {
        if ($p[$i] > 0) {
            $p[$i]--;
            $j = 0;
            if ($i % 2 == 1)
                $j = $p[$i];
            //swap
            $tmp = $set[$j];
            $set[$j] = $set[$i];
            $set[$i] = $tmp;
            $i = 1;
            $solutions[] = $set;
        }
        elseif($p[$i] == 0) {
            $p[$i] = $i;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $solutions;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your logic is equivalent to simply checking that the one or more keyword(s) are present in the database column, anywhere in the string/sentence.  If so, then a query of the following type might be sufficient for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    column LIKE CONCAT('%', 'foo', '%') AND
    column LIKE CONCAT('%', 'bar', '%')
```

If you plan on doing considerable work of this sort, it might be worth your while to invest some learning about MySQL's full text search capabilities.  If you had a full text index on your table, then a query like the following would also be close to what you have in mind:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST('foo,bar')
```

Comment: Not quite. Maybe I did not express this well in my question but if the search term has 2 words, I want both of them to be in the answer.

Comment: @JohnCarroll My query meets this requirement.  Did you bother to test it?  I check for the presence of each search term and only if all are present would a record be returned.

Comment: No I did not test, I read the explanation and thought that it was close but did not match. I will test now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `MATCH AGAINST` for all permutations of a string. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST ('foo bar');
```

matches : foo bar, bar foo, foo bar green, green bar foo, foo green bar, bar green foo, foo, bar

---

However, for your request, you can make some modification which to add `+` operator at every word of your search string:

```
$search_string = "foo bar";
$search_string = "+". str_replace(' ', " +", $search_string);
```

and run the sql like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST ('$search_string' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

matches : foo bar, bar foo, foo bar green, green bar foo, foo green bar, bar green foo

---

Remember to add fulltext index on column structure:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT (column);
```

---

Full text search reference : [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: This is closest to what I am looking for thus far. I didn't know about MATCH / AGAINST. Thanks for showing me! The only issue with it is that I do not want `foo bar` to match `foo` or `bar`. I would want it to match `foo bar`, `bar foo`, `bar foo green`, ...

Comment: Amazing - I will be curious to see how this tests speed wise against Tim's answer

Comment: Tim's answer (full text method) matches : foo bar, bar foo, foo bar green, green bar foo, foo green bar, bar green foo, foo, bar. Not the result you desired and he got the tick, lol

Comment: the search speed should be very fast because the column is under full text index

Answer (score 0):

I use my function in my projects :
this function chesk  does $column is similar to $what?

for example :

```
student = smith
what= mike smith
result:YES
```

https://3v4l.org/eUOS1

and in reverse too:

```
student =mikesmith
what= smith
result:YES

function TRIM_SEARCH_TABLE_UNIQ($column,$what)
{
 $Find=0;

   $e1=strpos('0'.trim(strtolower($column)),trim(strtolower($what)));
   $e2=strpos('0'.trim(($what)),trim(strtolower($column))); 
   if(($e1>0)||($e2>0))
        { 
            $Find=1;
            return "YES";
        }

 return "NO";
}
```

Comment: This is a handy function, however I want to perform the search while querying. Otherwise I would have to pull all rows (ALOT) and then perform this function.